# Configure backspace to delete files from project explorer

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, keyboard-shortcuts

I am trying to configure "backspace" key in eclipse to remove files from Project Explorer (the same shortcut like in Xcode and Android Studio).

In preferences for Delete command, I replaced old shortcut "FN+Backspace" with just "Backspace". After that, I can trigger Delete command in Project Explorer by "Backspace". Good.

But now in all text editors "Backspace" removes next symbol instead of previous one. I tried different shortcuts configurations for "Delete Next" and "Delete Previous" but I can't get it working as expected.

I want to use "Backspace" to delete files and usual shortcuts in the Text editor. Can I achieve it in Eclipse?

Comment: I guess you have to create a new key binding for _Backspace_ with _When_ set to _Text Editing_ (assuming your current _Backspace_ key binding is set to _When_ = _In Windows_).

Comment: @howlger thanks for the response. It is the greatest hack, and it is working! I bind Backspace in "Text Editing" for one of disabled command (for example, I used Delete Branch command).

Answer (score 1):

The solution from @howlger.

Bind Backspace in "Text Editing" for one of disabled command (for example, I used Delete Branch command).

Now, BS in Project Explorer triggers default Delete command, in Text Editors BS triggers disabled command and will delete the previous symbol.